Video game for PS4 with anime transforming military girls fighting against robots
In 2017-ish, I came across a Hack-and-slash video game with Anime-style girls as a budget game on my PS4.
The characters were military girls and they fought robots. They could also transform like they do in the Senran Kagura game series and the similarities between the two were very obvious to me.

It is not Senran Kagura, Valkyrie Drive, nor any other PS Vita game.

Probably not https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaNX0-6zRlQ either

Soul Saber? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7M4L5KDKNI

Senran Kagura Estival Versus came out on PS4 around the timeframe. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63i0F9YQwZo

https://www.gamepressure.com/games/ps4/manga-and-anime/
